# Drag selected text to move it?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to drag selected text to move it? This is in almost every other editor (not to mention text input fields in browsers.) I was surprised not to find it in VS Code.

Here is a [gif example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRzHb.gif).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is now supported as of Feb 2017 release (1.10.1) but it is disabled by default.

To enable it: Go to `File > Preferences > Settings` and add this line `"editor.dragAndDrop": true`

Source: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_10#_preview-drag-and-drop-selected-text

Comment: This is a feature that a good editor must have. Otherwise I wouldn't use VSC at all. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Adrian Good tips, although you might want to check your spelling of "shift" :-)

Comment: Oh my god, I feel like I regained my super powers! Together with select word `Ctrl+D`, move line `Alt-Up/Down Arrow` and, duplicate line `Alt-Shift-Up/Down Arrow` I feel like dancing on water instead of typing --UPDATED-- My  bad, sorry about this, seems the original comment was locked :-)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's not yet implemented, but there's [an open issue about it](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1046).

If you want to help without diving into the internals, go  the issue to add to its social signal.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so. [Their site](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/code-vs.aspx) says that it is keyboard-optimized and keyboard-centric, so their idea might be that you should highlight some text, cut it, and past it where you want it rather than dragging it.

Comment: Well it doesn't support Vim mode yet so it's not *that* keyboard-centric. Now need to find out if this is possible with an extension.

Comment: Regarding Vim: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/74th.vimStyle

Again, imperfect, but the current best effort.

It's true, there is a difference between claiming to be something and succeeding in it. As far as I can tell from what I've seen of the API, dragging text is not possible with an extension either. I haven't seen any API methods that use mouse events.

One could possibly make a selection, alt click somewhere else to create a new cursor, and then use a keyboard-shortcut to trigger a command to move the text...but at that point you might as well just quickly ctrl+x , ctrl+v

Comment: This isn't a particularly helpful answer. If "keyboard-centric" were the real reason, why would they implement selecting text with the mouse at all? More likely, this feature was lower priority than others.

Answer (score -1):

I talk about this problem on Github Microsoft page and Microsoft engineers [see this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/12718). I hope to solve it. (Please support by  on [this page](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/12718#issue-179419322).)

Comment: The linked issue has been closed as duplicated, so the link in @Joe's answer is better.