# VSCode smart select grow doesn't honour word separators

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

In VSCode, `items-ce|nter` grows to `items-[center]` when executing the `editor.action.smartSelect.grow` command; where `|` represents the cursor and `[]` represents the selection.

Is it possible for this command to honour my word separators (as in `editor.wordSeparators`) and grow straight to `[items-center]`?

Also, is it possible for smart select to ignore camel case? eg. `camelCa|se` grows to `camel[Case]` instead of `[camelCase]`.

Comment: "_Also, is it possible for smart select to ignore camel case? eg. camelCa|se grows to camel[Case] instead of [camelCase]._" one question per question post please. This should be moved to a new question post.

Comment: `"editor.wordSeparators": "\`~!@#$%^&*()=+[{]}\\|;\",.<>/?" // exclude -, ' and :`. I use this for `"[css][typescript][typescriptreact]"`, so I can quickly edit classNames like `sm:px-6`. Ctrl/Cmd+D honours these separators and works for this purpose, but it would be nice to be able to use the smart select in the same way, and also for camelCase.

Answer (score 0):

There is some help coming in vscode v1.80 (it is in the Insiders now).  A new setting:

```
Editor > Smart Select: Select Subwords  // default is enabled
Whether subwords (like 'foo` in 'fooBar' or 'foo_bar') should be selected.
```

The default is the current version where `camel[Case]` or `foo_[bar]` would be selected with the `smartSelect` command (brackets indicating the selections after using the command).

By disabling the setting mentioned above the result becomes `[camelCase]` or `[foo_bar]`.

So that helps with your camelCase question.  However, for `foo-bar`, the result is still `foo-[bar]` with the setting disabled **AND** the `"editor.wordSeparators"` setting modified to remove the `-`.  So apparently the `smartSelect` commands do not adjust to use the `"editor.wordSeparators"` value unfortunately.

I added a comment to the PR: see [Add option for smartSelect to ignore subwords](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/182571).  It looks like it is supposed to work for words like `foo-bar` but it doesn't for me.