# Dragging selected text to copy/move it within a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, clipboard

I'd like to replicate the behavior of dragging selected text, to move it in/into a text input or text area, within a webpage.

I'd like to know if it's possible (using a mouse drag of a selection) to:

1. <s>copy/move selected text from one text input to another</s>
2. <s>copy/move selected text within an input to another position</s>
3. copy/move selected text from a header/paragraph (i.e. non-input) to an input/textarea.
4. **populate the dragged text programmatically using javascript**
5. (Bonus: copy/move selected text to external program)

e.g. The green arrow demonstrates the behavior working, however, I'd like to make it work **within a webpage** (red arrow).

[image]

All google suggestions I've found so far, relate to dragging and dropping HTML elements, not text.

I'm using chrome, but bonus points if it's a cross-browser solution. Don't mind if the solution is HTML, CSS or javascript.

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33858029/drag-selected-text-to-move-it), but for visual studio code - not a webpage.

#### ** UPDATE **

I feel stupid (but I'll blame usability). If I select text, then **ensure the mouse isn't moving and click, THEN drag the mouse**, points 1-3 work as expected and drag the selected text. (my problem I suspect is that I was impatient, and subtlety moving the mouse before clicking to drag.)

@cjl750's answer still stands. I've changed the question to focus on point 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in my tests in Chrome, anything involving dropping into a text input is handled natively by the browser (and I would expect the same for other browsers). I am guessing whatever mouse events SO has connected to their search bar is interfering with drag and drop from there into another input, but any normal input I tested works fine.

That leaves you only needing to handle dragging into non-inputs.

There's two parts of that. First, you can get the current highlighted text with `window.getSelection()`. The tricky part is that you need to figure out what is under your cursor when you are done dragging that text somewhere. The solution on how to do that was inspired from [Solution #2 on this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444430/how-to-get-a-word-under-cursor-using-javascript#30586239).

We want to make use of `document.caretPositionFromPoint()`, but that's the new name for the method that is so far only supported in Firefox. So using the simple if/else statement [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/caretPositionFromPoint) we can cover everything but IE, which is what I'm doing in the snippet below. A more complete solution that includes IE support is found in the other link.

Basic strategy:

1. on `mousedown`, check for highlighted text
2. if we have some highlighted text, listen for the `dragend` event
3. assuming we stopped dragging on top of a text node, check cursor position within that node with `document.caretPositionFromPoint()` or `document.caretRangeFromPoint()`
4. using the caret position from #3 as well as the position of our highlighted text within its larger string, slice up our strings and output the result

```js
(() => {
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', checkForSelection);

  let textBeingDragged;
  let originalNode

  function checkForSelection(event) {
    const selection = window.getSelection();
    const selectedText = selection.toString();
    if (selectedText) {
      originalNode = selection.anchorNode.parentNode;
      textBeingDragged = selectedText;
      document.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd);
    }
  }
  
  function handleDragEnd(event) {
    const charRange = getCharPosition(event);
    const elemDrugOver = charRange.endContainer;
    if (elemDrugOver.nodeType === 3) {
      const offset = charRange.startOffset;
      const startText = elemDrugOver.wholeText.slice(0, offset);
      const endText = elemDrugOver.wholeText.slice(offset);
      elemDrugOver.textContent = `${startText}${textBeingDragged}${endText}`;
      
      const origText = originalNode.textContent;
      const indexOfSelection = origText.indexOf(textBeingDragged);
      const origStartText = origText.slice(0, indexOfSelection);
      const origEndText = origText.slice(offset + textBeingDragged.length);
      originalNode.textContent = `${origStartText}${origEndText}`;

      textBeingDragged = undefined;
      originalNode = undefined;
    }
    document.removeEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd);
  }
  
  function getCharPosition(event) {
    if (document.caretPositionFromPoint) {
      return document.caretPositionFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);
    } else if (document.caretRangeFromPoint) {
      return document.caretRangeFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);
    }
    return false;
  }
})();
```

```html
<h1>This is a (try to move me) header</h1>
<h2>This is another header</h2>
```

I'll leave it to you to add any enhancements you want, but this should get you 95% of the way there at least.

Comment: Hi @cjl750 - thanks for the response, tried the code snippet (here) and got "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'endContainer' of null" (dragged to stackoverflow searchbar). Will have a play and get back to you. (Thanks)

Comment: @NickGrealy well you would have to drag part of one of the headers within the snippet into the other one. I'm sure it doesn't work by dragging out of the snippet. They're not supposed to work that way.